# In SSI using Indy, how verifier chooses the schema for proof request?

Tags: aries, hyperledger-indy

In a Self Sovereign Identity, when verifier sends a proof request to the holder of credential, how the verifier makes sure to use correct schema id that is related to the holder during the proof request to the holder?

Answer (score 0):

I get more in depth and I can now say that the verifier can ask for a particular "schema_id" in the proof request's restrictions:(from [here](https://doc.ibmsecurity.verify-creds.com/develop/verify_proofs/))

```
{
  "name": "proof-schema1",
  "version": "1.0",
  "requested_attributes": [
    {
      "names": ["class", "grade"],
      "restrictions": [{"cred_def_id": "<cred-def-id>"}]
    }, 
    {
      "name": "phone_number"
    }
  ],
  "requested_predicates": [
    {
      "name": "rank",
      "p_type": "<=",
      "p_value": 10,
      "restrictions": [{"cred_def_id": "<cred-def-id>"}]
    }
  ],
  "cred_filter": [
    {
       "attr_name": "class",
       "attr_values": ["Math 100"]
       "exclude": true
    },
    {
       "attr_name": "class",
       "attr_values": ["Math *"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How the verifier know that a particular credential definition belongs to a prover or holder so that verifier can send a proof request?

Comment: The verifier doesn't know upfront if the holder/prover already holds the credential defined in the proof request